# Consume ASP.net Webservice in Cordova App

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I created an ASP.net webservice. The service returns a JSON string and is working fine. The service is running om http://domain.com/service.asmx/getUsers

Now, I also created a mobile site/Cordova app that consumes that service. The mobile site offcourse is running on http//domain2.com. If I open the html-code in Edge; it is running fine. If I open in Chrome It returns:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.com/service.asmx/getUsers. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

I think I have to change some settings in my IIS-server but I can't find what to change. Someone got a clue?